# How to identify when representations of solutions to trigonometric equations match (eg, $(2n\pm1)\frac\pi2$ and $(2n+1)\frac\pi2$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm not sure if "identifying" questions are allowed or not, if not a link or a point in the right direction would be great!

I am not able to tell if the two trigonometric equations are the same or not just by looking at them, unless I substitute values, which is not viable in competitive examinations.

For example,
$$(2n\pm1)\frac{\pi}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad (2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Let's say I get the first one, and the second one is one of four options. Is it possible to see them both and tell they are the same?

Another example:

$$(4n\pm1)\frac{\pi}{4}\quad\text{and}\quad(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: The first option clearly means an odd number times $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, so it is obvious both are the same thing. Now, for the second example, $2n+1$ represent all odd numbers, now see whether $4n \pm 1$ covers all odd numbers, if yes, then they are the same thing.

Comment: @Vilakshan That's it!? How embarrassing, could you copy-paste that so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging points is an unreliable method to show that two functions are equal.  It is too easy to choose points that coincidentally align, with the functions not being the same everywhere.

What you have to do is use identities to show that these functions are the same.

The basic ones are:

The definitions:
$\tan x = \frac {\sin x}{\cos x}\\
\sec x = \frac {1}{\cos x}\\
\csc x = \frac {1}{\sec x}$

The Pythagorean Theorem:
$\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$

The complementary angles:
$\sin x = \cos (\frac {\pi}{2} - x)\\
\tan x = \cot (\frac {\pi}{2} - x)\\
\sec x = \csc (\frac {\pi}{2} - x)$

The even / odd symmetry:
$\sin (-x) = -\sin x\\
\cos (-x) = \cos x$

Angle addition:
$\sin (A+B) = \sin A\cos B + \cos A\sin B\\
\cos (A+B) = \cos A\cos B - \sin A\sin B$

And rest follow from there.

e.g.

$\cos^2 x = \frac 12 \cos 2x + \frac 12\\
\frac 12 \cos (x+x) + \frac 12 \\
\frac 12 (\cos x\cos x - \sin x\sin x) + \frac 12 \\
\frac 12 \cos^2 x + \frac 12 (1- \sin^2 x) \\
\frac 12 \cos^2 x + \frac 12 (\cos^2 x) \\
\cos^2 x$